# MongoDB aggregation $group is very slow in pipeline but works decently grouping same collection from hard disk

Tags: performance, mongodb, grouping, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation query

```
db.banners.aggregate(
[ { '$match':
     { '$and':
        [ { ts: { '$gte': 1448920800000 } },
          { ts: { '$lte': 1449954261885 } },
          { '$or':
             [ { campaignId: { '$exists': true } },
               { clicks: { '$ne': [] } } ] } ] } },
  { '$sort': { ts: -1 } },
  { '$project':
     { siteId: 1,
       adslotId: 1,
       campaignId: { '$ifNull': [ '$campaignId', null ] },
       adslotElemId: 1,
       ts: 1,
       price: 1,
       adslotName: 1,
       impId: 1,
       siteDomain: 1,
       country: 1,
       browser: 1,
       browserVer: 1,
       os: 1,
       osVer: 1,
       ip: 1,
       kifUserUID: 1,
       wndLocHref: 1,
       cb: 1,
       ps: 1,
       clicks: 1,
       _id: 0,
       clickRev:
        { '$sum':
           { '$cond':
              [ '$campaignId',
                { '$map': { input: '$clicks', as: 'aux', in: '$$aux.price' } },
                0 ] } },
       clickCnt:
        { '$cond':
                           { '$cond':
           [ '$campaignId',
             { '$sum': { '$size': { '$ifNull': [ '$clicks', [] ] } } },
             0 ] } } },
  { '$project':
     { siteId: 1,
       adslotId: 1,
       campaignId: 1,
       adslotElemId: 1,
       ts: 1,
       price: 1,
       adslotName: 1,
       impId: 1,
       siteDomain: 1,
       country: 1,
       browser: 1,
       browserVer: 1,
       os: 1,
       osVer: 1,
       ip: 1,
       kifUserUID: 1,
       wndLocHref: 1,
       cb: 1,
       ps: 1,
       clicks: { '$cond': [ '$campaignId', null, '$clicks' ] },
       clickCnt: 1,
       clickRev: 1 } },
  { '$unwind': { path: '$clicks', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { '$project':
     { siteId: 1,
       adslotId: 1,
       campaignId: { '$ifNull': [ '$campaignId', '$clicks.campaignId' ] },
       adslotElemId: 1,
       ts: 1,
       price: { '$ifNull': [ '$price', '$clicks.price' ] },
       adslotName: 1,
       impId: { '$cond': [ '$campaignId', '$impId', '$clicks.impId' ] },
       siteDomain: 1,
       country: 1,
       browser: 1,
       browserVer: 1,
       os: 1,
       osVer: 1,
       ip: 1,
       wndLocHref: 1,
       cb: 1,
       ps: 1,
       clicks: 1,
       tsRange:
        { '$concat':
           [ { '$cond':
                [ { '$and':
                     [ { '$gt': [ '$ts', 1448920800000 ] },
                       { '$lte': [ '$ts', 1451512800000 ] } ] },
                  '1448920800000-',
                  '' ] } ] },
       clickCnt: 1,
       clickRev: 1 } },
  { '$out': 'result' }])
```

that outputs 3910424 documents into result collection. 
If I do for example

```
db.result.aggregate([{ $group: { _id:{country:'$country'}, c:{$sum: '$price'} }}]);
```

the answer is returned in 7 seconds.

However, when I replace `$out` stage with `$group: { _id:{country:'$country'}, c:{$sum: '$price'}` stage, the answer returns after ~3 mins.

My DB stats:

```
> db.stats()
{
    "db" : "logs",
    "collections" : 9,
    "objects" : 18904961,
    "avgObjSize" : 713.6041404158411,
    "dataSize" : 13490658444,
    "storageSize" : 17286610928,
    "numExtents" : 83,
    "indexes" : 13,
    "indexSize" : 1810174576,
    "fileSize" : 34276900864,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 68,
        "totalSize" : 11930017776
    },
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 22
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Hardware: 
32 GB,  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz

I would use `$out` as a solution to this slowness in grouping but the $out  itself is slow so the final time spent is about the same.

What's the explanation to the above?

Comment: Why all the stages and field selection if your end goal is that grouping? Surely this would just suffice: `db.banners.aggregate([{ "$match": { "ts": { "$gte": 1448920800000, "$lte": 1449954261885 }, "$or": [{ "campaignId": { "$exists": true } },{ "clicks.1": { "$exists": true } }] }},{ "$group": { "_id": "$country", "price": { "$sum": "$price" } }}])`, or at least basically along those lines ( note cleaner query as well ). There is also some work being done here with "price" out of the array which is likely not giving the result you think, so more data needed to clarify.

Comment: The general case here is you are doing a lot of things you don't need to, hence the slow down. No point in processing a `$sort` for example when the grouping of data does not rely on any specific order in processing the result.